Smooth factor-interactions in generalized additive models
I am currently trying to understand smooth-factor interactions in GAM-models, but I am having a hard time understanding the separation between main- and interaction effects. Consider the following simple function:
$$
f(x) = \sin(x) + A + A\times \cos(x), 
$$
where $A$ is a factor-variable that takes the values 0 or 1.
For me it makes sense to view the different terms as:
$\sin(x)$: Main effect due to covariate x
$A$: Main effect due to factor-variable
$A\times\cos(x)$: Interaction between A and x.
I now construct a synthetic dataset as follows:
data <- expand.grid(x = seq(0,10), A = c(0,1))
data$y <- sin(data$x) + data$A + data$A*cos(data$x)
data$A <- as.factor(data$A)

And I fit these using a simple interaction model:
model <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x) + A + ti(x, by = A),
                   data = data,
                   family = gaussian(),
                   method = "REML")

My naive expectation is that this model would be able to recover exactly the main and interactions effects above. But this is not what I see from the model summary or the resulting smooths. Is my model specification wrong or have I misunderstood smooth-factor interactions?
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x) + A + ti(x, by = A)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.12829    0.07626   1.682    0.126    
A1           0.96205    0.10785   8.920 7.28e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(x)     6.675  7.738 12.784 0.000457 ***
ti(x):A0 2.666  2.827  5.253 0.028219 *  
ti(x):A1 1.342  1.474  0.892 0.406407    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 18/19
R-sq.(adj) =  0.937   Deviance explained = 97.2%
-REML = 19.568  Scale est. = 0.063974  n = 22

s(x):

ti(x,A=0):

ti(x,A=1)


Either ti() is doing something weird because you're using it slightly unorthodoxly - your model is more typically fitted using
m1 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x) + A + s(x, by = A),
                data = data,
                family = gaussian(),
                method = "REML")

or, it's because your model contains terms that are bordering on being unidentifiable.
With the modified m1 above, I see
> summary(m1)

Family: gaussian
Link function: identity

Formula:
y ~ s(x) + A + s(x, by = A)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.128290   0.001319    97.3 9.94e-05 ***
A1          0.962050   0.001865   515.9 3.45e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf Ref.df       F p-value
s(x)    8.972  8.977 598.681 0.00167 **
s(x):A0 1.046  1.046   0.303 0.61117
s(x):A1 7.967  7.977 603.951 0.00165 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 28/29
R-sq.(adj) =      1   Deviance explained =  100%
-REML = 11.979  Scale est. = 1.9124e-05  n = 22

indicating that we do recover the data.
Note that ti() uses a different basis (bs = "cr") and k (5) compared to s() and that's likely a contributing factor to the lack of fit you were observing (you need more than 4 basis functions to model those sin/cos functions).
This model is often better specified now using the sz basis as that will make the "difference" smooths (the factor by ones) truly orthogonal to the main effect smooth:
m2 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x) + A + s(x, A, bs = "sz"),
                data = data,
                family = gaussian(),
                method = "REML")

which produces
> summary(m2)

Family: gaussian
Link function: identity

Formula:
y ~ s(x) + A + s(x, A, bs = "sz")

Parametric coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.6093150  0.0009333   652.9 2.18e-06 ***
A1          0.0000000  0.0000000     NaN      NaN
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df     F  p-value
s(x)   8.998      9 77609 1.73e-05 ***
s(x,A) 9.990     10 42171 2.51e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 20/21
R-sq.(adj) =      1   Deviance explained =  100%
-REML = 14.243  Scale est. = 1.9164e-05  n = 22

and

